# Selecting a node in virtualized TreeView with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

Is there a way to select manually a node in virtualizing TreeView and then bring it into view?

The data model I'm using with my TreeView is implemented based on the VM-M-V model. Each TreeViewItem's IsSelected property is binded to a corresponing property in ViewModel. I've also created a listener for TreeView's ItemSelected event where I call BringIntoView() for the selected TreeViewItem.

The problem with this approach seems to be that the ItemSelected event won't be raised until the actual TreeViewItem is created. So with the virtualization enabled node selection won't do anything until the TreeView is scrolled enough and then it jumps "magically" to the selected node when the event is finally raised.

I'd really like to use virtualization because I have thousands of nodes in my tree and I've already seen quite impressive performance improvements when the virtualization has been enabled.

Comment: Hi, I am also stuck with the same issue. You got any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 20):

The link Estifanos Kidane gave is broken. He probably meant [the "Changing selection in a virtualized TreeView" MSDN sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Changing-selection-in-a-6a6242c8/sourcecode?fileId=18862&pathId=753647475). however, this sample shows how to select a node in a tree, but using code-behind and not MVVM and binding, so it also doesn't handle the missing [SelectedItemChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditemchanged.aspx) when the bound SelectedItem is changed.

The only solution I can think of is to break the MVVM pattern, and when the ViewModel property that is bound to SelectedItem property changes, get the View and call a code-behind method (similar to the MSDN sample) that makes sure the new value is actually selected in the tree.

Here is the code I wrote to handle it. Suppose your data items are of type `Node` which has a `Parent` property:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I wrote the following behavior class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

public class NodeTreeSelectionBehavior : Behavior<TreeView>
{
    public Node SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (Node)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(Node), typeof(NodeTreeSelectionBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnSelectedItemChanged));

    private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newNode = e.NewValue as Node;
        if (newNode == null) return;
        var behavior = (NodeTreeSelectionBehavior)d;
        var tree = behavior.AssociatedObject;

        var nodeDynasty = new List<Node> { newNode };
        var parent = newNode.Parent;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            nodeDynasty.Insert(0, parent);
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }

        var currentParent = tree as ItemsControl;
        foreach (var node in nodeDynasty)
        {
            // first try the easy way
            var newParent = currentParent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(node) as TreeViewItem;
            if (newParent == null)
            {
                // if this failed, it's probably because of virtualization, and we will have to do it the hard way.
                // this code is influenced by TreeViewItem.ExpandRecursive decompiled code, and the MSDN sample at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Changing-selection-in-a-6a6242c8/sourcecode?fileId=18862&pathId=753647475
                // see also the question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/183636/46635
                currentParent.ApplyTemplate();
                var itemsPresenter = (ItemsPresenter)currentParent.Template.FindName("ItemsHost", currentParent);
                if (itemsPresenter != null)
                {
                    itemsPresenter.ApplyTemplate();
                }
                else
                {
                    currentParent.UpdateLayout();
                }

                var virtualizingPanel = GetItemsHost(currentParent) as VirtualizingPanel;
                CallEnsureGenerator(virtualizingPanel);
                var index = currentParent.Items.IndexOf(node);
                if (index < 0)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Node '" + node + "' cannot be fount in container");
                }
                CallBringIndexIntoView(virtualizingPanel, index);
                newParent = currentParent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as TreeViewItem;
            }

            if (newParent == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Tree view item cannot be found or created for node '" + node + "'");
            }

            if (node == newNode)
            {
                newParent.IsSelected = true;
                newParent.BringIntoView();
                break;
            }

            newParent.IsExpanded = true;
            currentParent = newParent;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged -= OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        SelectedItem = e.NewValue as Node;
    }

    #region Functions to get internal members using reflection

    // Some functionality we need is hidden in internal members, so we use reflection to get them

    #region ItemsControl.ItemsHost

    static readonly PropertyInfo ItemsHostPropertyInfo = typeof(ItemsControl).GetProperty("ItemsHost", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    private static Panel GetItemsHost(ItemsControl itemsControl)
    {
        Debug.Assert(itemsControl != null);
        return ItemsHostPropertyInfo.GetValue(itemsControl, null) as Panel;
    }

    #endregion ItemsControl.ItemsHost

    #region Panel.EnsureGenerator

    private static readonly MethodInfo EnsureGeneratorMethodInfo = typeof(Panel).GetMethod("EnsureGenerator", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    private static void CallEnsureGenerator(Panel panel)
    {
        Debug.Assert(panel != null);
        EnsureGeneratorMethodInfo.Invoke(panel, null);
    }

    #endregion Panel.EnsureGenerator

    #region VirtualizingPanel.BringIndexIntoView

    private static readonly MethodInfo BringIndexIntoViewMethodInfo = typeof(VirtualizingPanel).GetMethod("BringIndexIntoView", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    private static void CallBringIndexIntoView(VirtualizingPanel virtualizingPanel, int index)
    {
        Debug.Assert(virtualizingPanel != null);
        BringIndexIntoViewMethodInfo.Invoke(virtualizingPanel, new object[] { index });
    }

    #endregion VirtualizingPanel.BringIndexIntoView

    #endregion Functions to get internal members using reflection
}
```

With this class, you can write XAML like the following:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:NodeTreeSelectionBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TreeView>
    <Grid>
<UserControl>
```

Comment: +1: This is working well for me in Windows 7 / dotNet 4.0.  Does anyone know if the methods called through reflection are available in dotNet 4.5 or 4.5.1. (I will check myself but wanted to provide an opportunity for another developer to share their wisdom :)

Comment: @CameronPeters .Net 4.5 added BringIndexIntoViewPublic (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel.bringindexintoviewpublic.aspx), so if you are using .Net 4.5 or later, you can call it directly instead of getting it via reflection.

Comment: You guys are awesome - I manged to implement this solution - it does work in Windows 10 and it also works with the BringIndexIntoViewPublic method in .Net 4.5 - cool :-)

I used an interface as a reference instead of the actual node class - so, I guess the pattern is not completely broken.

I wonder if there is a replacement for the other
method: EnsureGenerator and Property: ItemsHost in 4.5 or later?

How come you have to use hidden items to do something so common?

Comment: Worked like a charm> You're a life saver, I've been searching for 16 hours about a solution ! I wish I can give you more than one plus!

Comment: Sometimes InvalidOperationException is thrown, Any Idea ?? @splintor

Comment: Sorry, but I no longer work with C#, so I can't help you.

Comment: Additionally, ItemsHost is available via IHierarchicalVirtualizationAndScrollInfo interface which TreeViewItem implements. EnsureGenerator can also be replaced with a call to virtualizingPanel.Children (which calls it), although this obscures the intent somewhat and could change between versions.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by creating custom controls for `TreeView`, `TreeViewItem` and `VirtualizingStackPanel`.
A part of the solution is from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Changing-selection-in-a-6a6242c8.

Each TreeItem (bound item) requires to know its parent (enforced by `ITreeItem`).

```
public interface ITreeItem {
    ITreeItem Parent { get; }
    IList<ITreeItem> Children { get; }
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
}
```

When `IsSelected` is set on any TreeItem the view model is notified and raises an event. The corresponding event listener in the view calls `BringItemIntoView` on the `TreeView`.

The `TreeView` finds all `TreeViewItems` on the path to the selected item and brings them into view.

And here the rest of the code:

```
public class SelectableVirtualizingTreeView : TreeView {
    public SelectableVirtualizingTreeView() {
        VirtualizingStackPanel.SetIsVirtualizing(this, true);
        VirtualizingStackPanel.SetVirtualizationMode(this, VirtualizationMode.Recycling);
        var panelfactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(SelectableVirtualizingStackPanel));
        panelfactory.SetValue(Panel.IsItemsHostProperty, true);
        var template = new ItemsPanelTemplate { VisualTree = panelfactory };
        ItemsPanel = template;
    }

    public void BringItemIntoView(ITreeItem treeItemViewModel) {
        if (treeItemViewModel == null) {
            return;
        }
        var stack = new Stack<ITreeItem>();
        stack.Push(treeItemViewModel);
        while (treeItemViewModel.Parent != null) {
            stack.Push(treeItemViewModel.Parent);
            treeItemViewModel = treeItemViewModel.Parent;
        }
        ItemsControl containerControl = this;
        while (stack.Count > 0) {
            var viewModel = stack.Pop();
            var treeViewItem = containerControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(viewModel);
            var virtualizingPanel = FindVisualChild<SelectableVirtualizingStackPanel>(containerControl);
            if (virtualizingPanel != null) {
                var index = viewModel.Parent != null ? viewModel.Parent.Children.IndexOf(viewModel) : Items.IndexOf(treeViewItem);
                virtualizingPanel.BringIntoView(index);
                Focus();
            }
            containerControl = (ItemsControl)treeViewItem;
        }
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride() {
        return new SelectableVirtualizingTreeViewItem();
    }

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item) {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        ((TreeViewItem)element).IsExpanded = true;
    }

    private static T FindVisualChild<T>(Visual visual) where T : Visual {
        for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++) {
            var child = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i);
            if (child == null) {
                continue;
            }
            var correctlyTyped = child as T;
            if (correctlyTyped != null) {
                return correctlyTyped;
            }
            var descendent = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (descendent != null) {
                return descendent;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class SelectableVirtualizingTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem {
    public SelectableVirtualizingTreeViewItem() {
        var panelfactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(SelectableVirtualizingStackPanel));
        panelfactory.SetValue(Panel.IsItemsHostProperty, true);
        var template = new ItemsPanelTemplate { VisualTree = panelfactory };
        ItemsPanel = template;
        SetBinding(IsSelectedProperty, new Binding("IsSelected"));
        SetBinding(IsExpandedProperty, new Binding("IsExpanded"));
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride() {
        return new SelectableVirtualizingTreeViewItem();
    }

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item) {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        ((TreeViewItem)element).IsExpanded = true;
    }
}

public class SelectableVirtualizingStackPanel : VirtualizingStackPanel {
    public void BringIntoView(int index) {
        if (index < 0) {
            return;
        }
        BringIndexIntoView(index);
    }
}

public abstract class TreeItemBase : ITreeItem {
    protected TreeItemBase() {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<ITreeItem>();
    }

    public ITreeItem Parent { get; protected set; }

    public IList<ITreeItem> Children { get; protected set; }

    public abstract bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public abstract bool IsExpanded { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler DescendantSelected;

    protected void RaiseDescendantSelected(TreeItemViewModel newItem) {
        if (Parent != null) {
            ((TreeItemViewModel)Parent).RaiseDescendantSelected(newItem);
        } else {
            var handler = DescendantSelected;
            if (handler != null) {
                handler.Invoke(newItem, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private TreeItemViewModel _selectedItem;

    public MainViewModel() {
        TreeItemViewModels = new List<TreeItemViewModel> { new TreeItemViewModel { Name = "Item" } };
        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            TreeItemViewModels[0].AddChildInitial();
        }
        TreeItemViewModels[0].IsSelected = true;
        TreeItemViewModels[0].DescendantSelected += OnDescendantSelected;
    }

    public event EventHandler DescendantSelected;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public List<TreeItemViewModel> TreeItemViewModels { get; private set; }

    public TreeItemViewModel SelectedItem {
        get {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set {
            if (_selectedItem == value) {
                return;
            }
            _selectedItem = value;
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) {
                handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedItem"));
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDescendantSelected(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
        var handler = DescendantSelected;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.Invoke(sender, eventArgs);
        }
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var mainViewModel = (MainViewModel)DataContext;
        mainViewModel.DescendantSelected += OnMainViewModelDescendantSelected;
    }

    private void OnAddButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var mainViewModel = (MainViewModel)DataContext;
        var treeItemViewModel = mainViewModel.SelectedItem;
        if (treeItemViewModel != null) {
            treeItemViewModel.AddChild();
        }
    }

    private void OnMainViewModelDescendantSelected(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
        _treeView.BringItemIntoView(sender as TreeItemViewModel);
    }

    private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e) {
        if (e.OldValue == e.NewValue) {
            return;
        }
        var treeView = (TreeView)sender;
        var treeItemviewModel = treeView.SelectedItem as TreeItemViewModel;
        var mainViewModel = (MainViewModel)DataContext;
        mainViewModel.SelectedItem = treeItemviewModel;
    }
}
```

And in XAML:

```
<controls:SelectableVirtualizingTreeView x:Name="_treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItemViewModels}" Margin="8" 
        SelectedItemChanged="OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged">
    <controls:SelectableVirtualizingTreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ... />
    </controls:SelectableVirtualizingTreeView.ItemTemplate>
</controls:SelectableVirtualizingTreeView>
```

Comment: For anybody looking for a simple code-behind solution: pull out `BringItemIntoView()` and call it right before you set `IsSelected=true` (using the usual two-way binding for `IsSelected` in your TreeViewItem ItemContainerStyle).  I spent a few hours playing with Behaviors, but setting `IsSelected` wasn't causing SelectedItem to change if the target item was off-screen, so the event wouldn't fire.  (I'm probably missing something simple, but I'm not using MVVM for my project.)

Comment: ...this doesn't entirely work, because setting` IsSelected` on one node won't clear it from the previously-selected node if the previous selection got recycled. (Click, scroll way down, click; when you scroll back up, the previous selection reasserts itself.)  Can be fixed with a trivial bit of code that clears the selection flag from all other items, but this is getting ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I used an attached property to solve this issue.

```
public class TreeViewItemBehaviour
{
    #region IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected

    public static bool GetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
    {
        return (bool)treeViewItem.GetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(
      TreeViewItem treeViewItem, bool value)
    {
        treeViewItem.SetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(TreeViewItemBehaviour),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged));

    static void OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged(
      DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = depObj as TreeViewItem;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            item.Loaded += item_Loaded;
        }
        else
        {
            item.Loaded -= item_Loaded;
        }
    }

    static void item_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
        if (item != null)
            item.BringIntoView();
    }

    #endregion // IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected

}
```

And in my XAML style for a TreeViewItem, I just set the property to true

```
<Setter Property="Behaviours:TreeViewItemBehaviour.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected" Value="True" />
```

HTH

Comment: When you use a virtualized TreeView then the TreeViewItem you wish to select most likely isn't created yet -- so it's absolutely useless to apply any Style for TreeViewItem.

Answer (score 1):

If you used this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9206992/8559138) decision and sometimes get InvalidOperationException, you can use my fixed decision:

I update currentParent layout if newParent is null and trying get ContainerFromIndex again.

```
 newParent = currentParent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as TreeViewItem;
 if (newParent == null)
 {
      currentParent.UpdateLayout();
      virtualizingPanel.BringIndexIntoViewPublic(index);
      newParent = currentParent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as TreeViewItem;
 }
```

Full decision:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

public class NodeTreeSelectionBehavior : Behavior<TreeView>
{
    public INode SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (INode)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(Node), typeof(NodeTreeSelectionBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnSelectedItemChanged));

    private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newNode = e.NewValue as INode;
        if (newNode == null) return;
        var behavior = (NodeTreeSelectionBehavior)d;
        var tree = behavior.AssociatedObject;

        var nodeDynasty = new List<INode> { newNode };
        var parent = newNode.Parent;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            nodeDynasty.Insert(0, parent);
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }

        var currentParent = tree as ItemsControl;
        foreach (var node in nodeDynasty)
        {
            // first try the easy way
            var newParent = currentParent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(node) as TreeViewItem;
            var index = 0;
            VirtualizingPanel virtualizingPanel = null;
            if (newParent == null)
            {
                // if this failed, it's probably because of virtualization, and we will have to do it the hard way.
                // this code is influenced by TreeViewItem.ExpandRecursive decompiled code, and the MSDN sample at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Changing-selection-in-a-6a6242c8/sourcecode?fileId=18862&pathId=753647475
                // see also the question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/183636/46635
                currentParent.ApplyTemplate();
                var itemsPresenter = (ItemsPresenter)currentParent.Template.FindName("ItemsHost", currentParent);
                if (itemsPresenter != null)
                {
                    itemsPresenter.ApplyTemplate();
                }
                else
                {
                    currentParent.UpdateLayout();
                }

                virtualizingPanel = GetItemsHost(currentParent) as VirtualizingPanel;
                CallEnsureGenerator(virtualizingPanel);
                index = currentParent.Items.IndexOf(node);
                if (index < 0)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Node '" + node + "' cannot be fount in container");
                }
                if (virtualizingPanel != null)
                {
                    virtualizingPanel.BringIndexIntoViewPublic(index);
                }
                newParent = currentParent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as TreeViewItem;
                if (newParent == null)
                {
                    currentParent.UpdateLayout();
                    virtualizingPanel.BringIndexIntoViewPublic(index);
                    newParent = currentParent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as TreeViewItem;
                }
            }

            if (newParent == null)
            {
                  throw new InvalidOperationException("Tree view item cannot be found or created for node '" + node + "'");
            }

            if (node == newNode)
            {
                newParent.IsSelected = true;
                newParent.BringIntoView();
                break;
            }

            newParent.IsExpanded = true;
            currentParent = newParent;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged -= OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        SelectedItem = e.NewValue as INode;
    }

    #region Functions to get internal members using reflection

    // Some functionality we need is hidden in internal members, so we use reflection to get them

    #region ItemsControl.ItemsHost

    static readonly PropertyInfo ItemsHostPropertyInfo = typeof(ItemsControl).GetProperty("ItemsHost", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    private static Panel GetItemsHost(ItemsControl itemsControl)
    {
        Debug.Assert(itemsControl != null);
        return ItemsHostPropertyInfo.GetValue(itemsControl, null) as Panel;
    }

    #endregion ItemsControl.ItemsHost

    #region Panel.EnsureGenerator

    private static readonly MethodInfo EnsureGeneratorMethodInfo = typeof(Panel).GetMethod("EnsureGenerator", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    private static void CallEnsureGenerator(Panel panel)
    {
        Debug.Assert(panel != null);
        EnsureGeneratorMethodInfo.Invoke(panel, null);
    }

    #endregion Panel.EnsureGenerator

    #endregion Functions to get internal members using reflection
}
```

And XAML:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject">
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:NodeTreeSelectionBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TreeView>
<Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example taken from an [MSDN Question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a74f22cc-5f82-4070-9f32-c6985dbdead5/)
        public void ScrollToItem(int index)

```
    {

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,

            (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperationCallback)delegate(object arg)

            {

                int N = fileList.Items.Count;

                if (N == 0)

                    return null;

                if (index < 0)

                {

                    fileList.ScrollIntoView(fileList.Items[0]); // scroll to first

                }

                else

                {

                    if (index < N)

                    {

                        fileList.ScrollIntoView(fileList.Items[index]); // scroll to item

                    }

                    else

                    {

                        fileList.ScrollIntoView(fileList.Items[N - 1]); // scroll to last

                    }

                }

                return null;

            }, null);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as there's a new answer recently posted to this question, I'll add my $0.02 into the mix with a MVVM pure solution to this issue.

Given [perTreeViewItemViewModelBase](https://github.com/Peregrine66/PeregrinesView/blob/master/library/Peregrine.WPF.ViewModel/perTreeViewItemViewModelBase.cs) as a base class for treeview item data, you can create a bindable selected item property on the TreeView using an attached property.

```
public class perTreeViewHelper : Behavior<TreeView>
{
    public object BoundSelectedItem
    {
        get { return GetValue(BoundSelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BoundSelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundSelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BoundSelectedItem",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(perTreeViewHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                OnBoundSelectedItemChanged));

    private static void OnBoundSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = args.NewValue as perTreeViewItemViewModelBase;

        if (item != null)
            item.IsSelected = true;
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged -= OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object obj, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> args)
    {
        BoundSelectedItem = args.NewValue;
    }
}
```

A second helper class handles scrolling TreeViewItems into view. There are two distinct cases

- when an item is selected
- when an item is expanded, the tree is scrolled to show as many child items as possible

Note the use of dispatcher priority, which ensures that any virtualised items are fully formed before we try to scroll them into view.

```
public static class perTreeViewItemHelper
{
    public static bool GetBringSelectedItemIntoView(TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
    {
        return (bool)treeViewItem.GetValue(BringSelectedItemIntoViewProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBringSelectedItemIntoView(TreeViewItem treeViewItem, bool value)
    {
        treeViewItem.SetValue(BringSelectedItemIntoViewProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BringSelectedItemIntoViewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "BringSelectedItemIntoView",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(perTreeViewItemHelper),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, BringSelectedItemIntoViewChanged));

    private static void BringSelectedItemIntoViewChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!(args.NewValue is bool))
            return;

        var item = obj as TreeViewItem;

        if (item == null)
            return;

        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
            item.Selected += OnTreeViewItemSelected;
        else
            item.Selected -= OnTreeViewItemSelected;
    }

    private static void OnTreeViewItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
        item?.BringIntoView();

        // prevent this event bubbling up to any parent nodes
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    public static bool GetBringExpandedChildrenIntoView(TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
    {
        return (bool)treeViewItem.GetValue(BringExpandedChildrenIntoViewProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBringExpandedChildrenIntoView(TreeViewItem treeViewItem, bool value)
    {
        treeViewItem.SetValue(BringExpandedChildrenIntoViewProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BringExpandedChildrenIntoViewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "BringExpandedChildrenIntoView",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(perTreeViewItemHelper),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, BringExpandedChildrenIntoViewChanged));

    private static void BringExpandedChildrenIntoViewChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!(args.NewValue is bool))
            return;

        var item = obj as TreeViewItem;

        if (item == null)
            return;

        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
            item.Expanded += OnTreeViewItemExpanded;
        else
            item.Expanded -= OnTreeViewItemExpanded;
    }

    private static void OnTreeViewItemExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;

        if (item == null)
            return;

        // use DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, so that we wait for all of the UI elements for any newly visible children to be created

        // first bring the last child into view
        Action action = () =>
        {
            var lastChild = item.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(item.Items.Count - 1) as TreeViewItem;
            lastChild?.BringIntoView();
        };

        item.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

        // then bring the expanded item (back) into view
        action = () => { item.BringIntoView(); };
        item.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

        // prevent this event bubbling up to any parent nodes
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This helper class can be included in a style for TreeView controls.

```
<Style x:Key="perExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid Width="10"
                      Height="10"
                      Background="Transparent">
                    <Path x:Name="ExpanderGlyph"
                          Margin="1"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Data="M 0,3 L 0,5 L 3,5 L 3,8 L 5,8 L 5,5 L 8,5 L 8,3 L 5,3 L 5,0 L 3,0 L 3,3 z"
                          Fill="LightGreen"
                          Stretch="None" />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ExpanderGlyph" Property="Data" Value="M 0,0 M 8,8 M 0,3 L 0,5 L 8,5 L 8,3 z" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ExpanderGlyph" Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="ExpanderGlyph" Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="perTreeViewItemContainerStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">

    <!-- Link the properties of perTreeViewItemViewModelBase to the corresponding ones on the TreeViewItem -->
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />

    <!-- Include the two "Scroll into View" behaviors -->
    <Setter Property="vhelp:perTreeViewItemHelper.BringSelectedItemIntoView" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="vhelp:perTreeViewItemHelper.BringExpandedChildrenIntoView" Value="True" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                          MinWidth="14" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  ClickMode="Press"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  Style="{StaticResource perExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" />

                    <Border x:Name="PART_Border"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                          Margin="0,2"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          ContentSource="Header" />

                    </Border>

                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="1" />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <!--  Use the same colors for a selected item, whether the TreeView is focussed or not  -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource perTreeViewItemContainerStyle}" />
</Style>
```

I've covered this in more detail in a recent [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/).

Answer (score 0):

An update of [@splintor's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9206992/1807542), using some modern C# features, and does without any reflection.

```
public class Node
{
    public Node Parent { get; set; }
}

public class NodeTreeSelectionBehavior : Behavior<TreeView>
{
    public Node SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (Node)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SelectedItem",
            typeof(Node),
            typeof(NodeTreeSelectionBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnSelectedItemChanged));

    private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.NewValue is Node newNode)) return;

        var treeView = ((NodeTreeSelectionBehavior)d).AssociatedObject;

        var ancestors = new List<Node> { newNode };
        var parent = newNode;
        while ((parent = parent.Parent) != null)
        {
            ancestors.Insert(0, parent);
        }

        var currentParent = treeView as ItemsControl;
        foreach (var node in ancestors)
        {
            // first try the easy way
            var newParent = currentParent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(node) as TreeViewItem;
            if (newParent == null)
            {
                // if this failed, it's probably because of virtualization, and we will have to do it the hard way.
                // see also the question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/183636/46635
                var itemsPresenter = (ItemsPresenter)currentParent.Template.FindName("ItemsHost", currentParent);
                var virtualizingPanel = (VirtualizingPanel)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(itemsPresenter, 0);
                var index = currentParent.Items.IndexOf(node);
                if (index < 0)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Node '" + node + "' cannot be fount in container");
                }
                virtualizingPanel.BringIndexIntoViewPublic(index);
                newParent = currentParent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as TreeViewItem;
            }

            if (newParent == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Tree view item cannot be found or created for node '" + node + "'");
            }

            if (node == newNode)
            {
                newParent.IsSelected = true;
                newParent.BringIntoView();
                break;
            }

            newParent.IsExpanded = true;
            currentParent = newParent;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged -= OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        SelectedItem = e.NewValue as Node;
    }
}
```

Used in the same way:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:NodeTreeSelectionBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TreeView>
    <Grid>
<UserControl>
```